# How to Settimeout to display multiple divs with if function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, settimeout

So I have a simple javascript that looks like this

```
function  myfunction(){

var a = [document.getElementById("div1"),
document.getElementById("div2"), document.getElementById("div3")];

if(a.style.display=="none"){

setTimeout(function(){a.style.display="block";},4000);
}

}
```

And html code looks like this

```
<  a href="#" onclick="myfunction();"  >   click to show div1 and div2 after 4 seconds<   /a  >

<  p id="div1"   style="display:none;" >divv1<  /p  >


<  p id="div2"    style="display:none;"    >divv2<  /p  >



<  p id="div3"    style="display:none;"    >divv3<  /p  >
```

However divs are not showing after 4 seconds  after I clicked.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Can someone please guide me further?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

var `a` is the array, so you need to set the style for all the elements of the array.

```js
function myfunction() {

  var a = [document.getElementById("div1"),
    document.getElementById("div2"), document.getElementById("div3")
  ];

  if (a[0].style.display == "none" && a[1].style.display == "none" && a[2].style.display == "none") {

    setTimeout(function() {
      a.forEach(item => item.style.display = "block");
    }, 4000);
  }

}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction();"> click to show div1 and div2 after 4 seconds
  </a>

<p id="div1" style="display:none;">divv1
</p>


<p id="div2" style="display:none;">divv2
</p>



<p id="div3" style="display:none;">divv3
</p>
```

Comment: Why won't && work in this condition? Such as if(document.getElementById("div1").style.display=="none"&&document.getElementById("div2").style.display=="none"&&document.getElementById("div3").style.display=="none"){//settimeout}? Please guide me further. Thanks alot!

Comment: just don't need to check all of the divs, but only one div display css check is fine because you set all the divs display to block in the setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

a is an array. It does not have a style property. You have to iterate over the array and change the display property for each.

```
function  myfunction() {

  var a = document.querySelectorAll("p") ;

  a.forEach( div => {
    if(div.style.display == "none"){
      setTimeout(function() {
        div.style.display = "block";
      }, 4000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. I'd like to ask why won't && work in this condition? Such as if(document.getElementById("div1").style.display=="none"&&document.getElementById("div2").style.display=="none"&&document.getElementById("div3").style.display=="none"){//settimeout}? Please guide me further. Thanks alot!

Comment: The condition work's fine. Waht is the problem here?